# Unable to connect with uget-integrator

Tags: firefox-extensions

[image]

```
$ firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 60.0.1
```

I add the firefox addon but can't connect with that.

Comment: I am also having this same issue but with Chrome (Chromium 67) on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue on Opera and Firefox browser (on Ubuntu 18.04.1).

**Type this on terminal**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uget-team/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install uget-integrator
```

Then restart your browser.

**Edit:** You can visit [Source](https://github.com/ugetdm/uget-integrator/wiki/Installation#install-uget-integrator) for another distributions/OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you install for another distro, make sure you have `curl` installed.

The script to install `uget-integration`, not test curl. 
The script advises for error but complete install and `uget-integration` not work.

example:

```
root:/home/pippo# ./install_uget_integrator.sh 
./install_uget_integrator.sh: 4: ./install_uget_integrator.sh: curl: not found
Installing uget-integrator 
uget-integrator is installed successfully!
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that hint. It worked on OpenSuSE Tumbleweed with Firefox. Curl and it's devel-packets are installed.

Bye
Michael

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1281541)